# Finding library during compilation in mingw64 environment (libgcrypt and libgpg-error)

Tags: ffmpeg, mingw-w64, libgcrypt

I'm a real beginner at this, so apologies in advance for obvious questions. I'm trying to compile a custom build of ffmpeg that has some extra dependencies the normal build does not. Among those is `libgcrypt` and `libgpg-error` - I know this, because when I run `configure`, it fails, and the log contains:

```
C:/workspace/windows/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lgcrypt
C:/workspace/windows/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lgpg-error
```

With this in mind, I cloned the repo for libgpg-error, ran `make` and `make install`, which created `libgpg-error.dll.a` and `libgpg-error.la` in `/home/myuser/w64root/lib`. I've tried adding this path to my `$LIB` environment variable, but the configure run still says it can't find the library.

How can I make it visible? I also have `pkg-config` available on the machine - would manually creating a `.pc` file help me any?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you run `./configure -h`, you should see this in the output:

```
Some influential environment variables:
  CC          C compiler command
  CFLAGS      C compiler flags
  LDFLAGS     linker flags, e.g. -L<lib dir> if you have libraries in a
              nonstandard directory <lib dir>
  LIBS        libraries to pass to the linker, e.g. -l<library>
  CPPFLAGS    (Objective) C/C++ preprocessor flags, e.g. -I<include dir> if
              you have headers in a nonstandard directory <include dir>
  CPP         C preprocessor
  CXX         C++ compiler command
  CXXFLAGS    C++ compiler flags
```

Note `LDFLAGS` in particular. That covers your case, since `/home/myuser/w64root/lib`
is not among the linker's standard search directories. Therefore run:

```
export LDFLAGS='-L/home/myuser/w64root/lib'; ./configure
```

and you should be OK.